# Do circles exist

Tags: geometry, irrational-numbers, philosophy

So I was wondering about circles today and if they really do exsist. If you graph a circle in function mode, your equation looks like$$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ Now for simple purposes lets take a portion of the graph in the first quadrant , so you have a fourth of the circle. Now the area of this section should be $$\frac{\pi}{4}$$ So we take the definite integral $$\int_0^1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$$ to get the area under this section. To do this numerically, we take the anti-derivative which is $$\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\operatorname{arcsin}(x)\right)$$ evaluated from 0 to 1, which gives us $\pi/4$. Now just being curious, the series expansion of $\operatorname{arcsin}(x)$ converges for $|x| < 1$. So once 1 is placed into $\operatorname{arcsin}$, does it only give us a rounded answer which never ends? Does this mean $\pi$ really does never end, which would mean the area of a circle is undefined making circles impossible? Probably flawed but still makes me think.

Comment: $\pi$ is irrational, so its decimal expansion never ends, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would say that, flawed or not, if it makes you think it's worth asking! +1!

Comment: @OP: The notion of "existence" is a complicated concept. What do you mean by "exists"?

Comment: There is a difference between "undefined" and that "it does not end". The set of natural number is defined but "does not end".

Comment: Well you can never find out the "true" answer or the exact answer involving pie, so by existing, I'm referring to having the ability to out put a single answer.

Comment: Modify Descartes' argument : when we describe the graph of a circle with a compass the circle says : "I'm circling, therefore I exist".

Comment: @user150070 You can never find enough pie! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Circles are clearly defined, as geometrical loci.

What is problematic is their *area*. It does exist, of course, as the "inside part", but what about its *size*?

This is a problem that has been around almost since circles were studied (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_circle)).

Its size exist as a [real number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number). Yes, it is problematic. But not enough for it not to exist mathematically.